# Animating properties of the content of a template in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation

Let's say I have a control like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton}">
     <Polygon Style="{StaticResource MyButtonIcon}"
              Points="... some points ..." />
</Button>
```

**MyButton** is the style for the background of the button while **MyButtonIcon** is the style of the button icon polygon itself. I'd like to subtly animate the button when the user hovers the mouse over the button. I can manage to animate the background (defined in MyButton) the usual way in the template *(VisualStateManager / VisualState / MouseOver / StoryBoard / ColorAnimation)*. To get an idea, my ColorAnimation declaration looks something likes this:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundTop"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                To="#FFFFFF"
                Duration="0:0:0.200" />
```

This works well for the background. However, I'd like to animate the colours of the gradient stops of the content polygon as well. I can't just put the animation in MyButtonIcon because I want the polygon to be animated when the mouse hovers over anywhere the button, not just the polygon within the button. I suppose it will look something like this:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyContentPresenter"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Some.Really.Long.Path.Color"
                To="#FFFFFF"
                Duration="0:0:0.200" />
```

The question is: what should be the value of "Some.Really.Long.Path.Color"? That is, say for instance, if I want to access the color property of the first gradient stop of the "Fill" of the polygon inside the content presenter, how would I go by doing that? Or am I trying to do it in a completely wrong way?

I hope I was clear and provided enough details, let me know if you need to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `Storyboard.TargetProperty` in your `ColorAnimation`:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty =
"(MyContentPresenter.MyButtonIcon.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
```

I'm not sure if the `(MyContentPresenter.MyButtonIcon.Fill)` part is right, but the rest of it should be. If this doesn't work, play around with `(MyContentPresenter.MyButtonIcon.Fill)` until it's pointing to your `GradientBrush`, and the rest should fall into place.

And I suppose it goes without saying, but I'll say it just in case: `(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0]` refers to the first `GradientStop` within your `GradientBrush`; just change the index to refer to a different one.

Hope this helps!